# Select multiple rows by chosing two indexed columns

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select ALL productId´s from product_parameter table by specifing conditions of same columns. Here is working example

```
SELECT PROD.productId FROM product PROD
LEFT JOIN product_parameter PARAM ON PROD.`productId` = PARAM.`productId`
WHERE PROD.`publish` = 1 AND ( PARAM.`parameterId` = "264" AND PARAM.`valueId` = 10 )
```

It selects several products

```
productId parameterId valueId
3328        264         10
3514        264         10
3513        264         10
3512        264         10
```

When I display all parameters for productId 3328 or 3514 I see they have parameterId 247 and valueId 60 IN COMMON, now here is the tricky part. I would like to create a query which selects those two productId by adding another condition like

```
AND ( PARAM.`parameterId` = "247" AND PARAM.`valueId` = 60 )
```

But logicaly it can not work cause I am trying to select a row which should contain two valueId (no sense) I have been looking into several product parameter system p.e. joomshopping uses a separate columns for every new parameter which in my case would create 600+ columns for each row

VERY IMPORTANT I know i can put OR between every parameter GROUP but this would give me just a number of all products existing for combination of those conditions my goal is to select **EXACT** number of productIds which meets my condition any IDEAS?